Cargo workspace with multiple executables in docker
I have the following structure.
- Wrokspace
 - Service 1
   - Cargo.toml
 - Service 2
   - Cargo.toml

The project is a bit more complex but the main part is that i have multiple executables like service 1 and 2.
Currently I am creating a separate file for both Dockerfile.service_1, Dockerfile.service_2 where every file contains cargo-chef setup and than it contains setup for the specific executable. Now here comes the issue, because I am using workspace  when running.
FROM chef AS builder 
COPY --from=planner /src/recipe.json recipe.json
# Build dependencies - this is the caching Docker layer!
RUN cargo chef cook --release --recipe-path recipe.json
# Build application
COPY . .
RUN cargo build --release --bin app

This means it builds all the crates for the whole workspace and not only the ones for the specific service. How can I handle this better, I would like to builds the crates only once and than cache the "builder" and use it for as many services as I have.
Not sure if this is also the best approach, I am just trying to have multiple executables running with my workspace with multiple docker files. Any ideas are welcome.

Is each Service a self-contained cargo package that should be deployed as a standalone service? If so, I think your problem is COPY . .. Why copy everything if you only need the source for one service?

Yes each service should be deployed as a standalone service, but it uses workspace to get it's crates. There is only one target folder because of having a workspace, so not sure how to achieve what you are saying exactly.

It's hard to suggest anything without understanding the structure, but it definitely seems like each service should be isolated and buildable on its own. That way you could easily build each Dockerfile without being concerned with any other.

They are buildable on their own, and it does work, but when you are working woth cargo workspaces you have your cargo crates shared from that workspace to the services this way you don't need to get the same crates multiple times, that's why cargo worksapce is very nice, but because of that I am trying to understand how to do the Dockerfile setup, because cargo workspace needs to get all crates in order to shared them to the services. Not sure how to approach that.

I think it's fine to share workspace packages when developing to save space, but when you deploy each container should download and install its own packages. The point of a Dockerfile is to encapsulate exactly what you need and nothing more. Does that make sense?
